# GStreamer vorbis encoder warning (Invalid channel positions) for more than 8 channel

Tags: gstreamer, oggvorbis

I have a pipeline `appsrc->rawaudioparse->audioconvert->vorbisenc->oggmux->filesink`.
In the **appsrc**, i push data in buffer. data have 16 channel and are in a float array with interleaved layout (ch1, ch2, ch3,.....,ch16,ch1, ch2,....,ch16). **rawaudioparse** properties are:

```
g_object_set(G_OBJECT(parser) , "pcm-format", 28, // f32le: GST_AUDIO_FORMAT_F32LE
                                "num-channels", 16,
                                "sample-rate", 100,
                                "interleaved", TRUE,
                                 NULL);
```

Pipeline seems to be working well but I get a warning that worries me. This warning only appears when I set the number of channels to more than 8.

```
** (encoder:3785): WARNING **: 07:56:10.576: Invalid channel positions.
```

There's a Property called **channel-positions** in the rawaudioparse, but I don't know how to set it.

Does anyone know why this warning exists for more than 8 channels and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Check https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/audio/gstaudiochannels.html?gi-language=c#GstAudioChannelPosition for `GstAudioChannelPosition`.

Since for so many channels there is no point for positions anymore I would try adding to your `g_object_set`:

```
"channel-positions", GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE,
```

I wonder why it wouldn't set that automatically though if you set the number of channels higher than 8..

If the warning persists I would double check the caps the elements agreed on. The `channel-mask` should be `0x0` if it is set.

Apart from that, that warning just tells you that there is a channel-position set but doesn't add up with rest of the format and probably will just be ignored (which is the same result as telling it upfront that there are no positions).

Comment: Thanks. When I set the  "channel-position" :GST_AUDIO_CHANNEL_POSITION_NONE , I hit Error "Segmentation fault (core dumped)"

Comment: Maybe it wants a pointer to such variable. Have a closer look at the docs. When in question take a peek at the source.